# Path.GetDirectoryName produces Win32Exception 'Access is denied'

Tags: c#, process, try-catch

Hi I am currently trying to obtain the directory of a running process and keep obtaining the Error
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied'
The following code I am using below and I am currently using a try catch to prevent this error, however a try catch proves to be a slow method requiring valuable processing time, and I am here to ask if there is a method to detect if a process's data is accessible via boolean to prevent a try catch statement from being required and therefore decrease processing time.

```
string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(process.MainModule.FileName)
```

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469576/access-to-folder-denied-c-sharp) answer your question?

Comment: And in which directory is this file?

Comment: It may be slow, but how often do you need to get the directory name? Are you concerned that the program might be skulking around to different directories while executing? It looks like a good place to use a singleton and cache the result in a `static` on the first access. The status can be kept in another `static` and you can promptly return both values.

Comment: I’m pretty much obtaining the directory name all the time, the program is intended to see if there are any blacklisted processes running, decided by specific criteria such as the path of the process, and then kill all processes that are blacklisted. I’m using this atm to block directories such as the steamapps folder, pretty much banning all steam games. For caching the data, would I store copies of the processes in a list or?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that you were looking at _other_ processes. Even so, I'd cache the `Id` and `StartTime` and any additional information you need. The `Id`/`StartTime` pair should be unique. (Id's are reused, but it is unlikely that one would be used so briefly and reused so quickly that the `StartTime` would not change.) A [`Hashtable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=netframework-4.8) would be a suitable collection with the `key` being an `Id`/`StartTime` pair and the `value` being any other data needed. Don't forget to remove old processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for the `Process.MainModule` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainmodule?view=netframework-4.8), you can see that it throws a `Win32Exception` if a 32-bit process tries to access a 64-bit process. You can check whether this is the case by looking at the [`Win32Exception.ErrorCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/18d8fbe8-a967-4f1c-ae50-99ca8e491d2d?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (I assume 0x00000005 in this case) and `Win32Exception.Message` properties. And you can retrieve the bitness of your process by evaluating `Environment.Is64BitProcess`.

Even running as a 64-bit process your program won't be allowed to access `MainModule` of a System process (4) or a [System Idle Process](https://askleo.com/what_is_the_system_idle_process_and_why_is_it_using_most_of_the_cpu/) (0). This will throw a `Win32Exception` with the message:

> Unable to enumerate the process modules.

You can use [Process.Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.id?view=netframework-4.8) to check for 0 or 4.

Alternatively the Win32 API allows you to query every process with the *LimitedQueryInformation* flag, which means you can check the path without receiving an exception. Unfortunately the .NET Base Class Library doesn't expose this flag, so you need P/Invoke to do that. **The following C# console program never triggers an exception** (when run on my local machine). If it's run with local admin privileges, it returns all path names except for process 0 and process 4. If it's run as a normal user, it understandably only lists the pathnames for those processes to which it has access.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace NewCmd
{
    class Program
    {
        [Flags]
        private enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
        {
            QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool QueryFullProcessImageName
            (
            [In] IntPtr hProcess, 
            [In] int dwFlags, 
            [Out] StringBuilder lpExeName, 
            ref int lpdwSize
            );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess
            (
            ProcessAccessFlags processAccess, 
            bool bInheritHandle, 
            int processId
            );

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Id: {0} Name: {1}", p.Id, p.ProcessName));
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Path: {0}", GetProcessFilename(p)));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static String GetProcessFilename(Process p)
        {
            int capacity = 2000;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(capacity);
            IntPtr ptr = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.QueryLimitedInformation, false, p.Id);
            if (QueryFullProcessImageName(ptr, 0, builder, ref capacity))
            {
                return builder.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return "[Missing]";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, is there a way to identify if it’s a system process seperate to a try catch to avoid the exception?

Comment: @SebastianSouthwell, I've edited my answer to respond to your comment.

Comment: Thank You, I implemented your adjustments, it works like a charm, got processing time down from 3 seconds to 0.15 now, which is below what I need and just perfect thanks.